# Select nested AND OR. How?

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison

Below I have an SQL query that servers as a login script for users who choose to either type in their username or email.

I've noticed that even though it seems it would check for either or as a login credential in doesn't.

`username1 OR username1@email.com` = Only really looking up by username

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblaccount 
WHERE acc_user='username1' OR acc_email='username1@email.com' 
  AND acc_password='letmein1' AND acc_confirmed='1' AND acc_active='1'
```

...if I alter it to...

`username0 OR username1@email.com` = It does not return a record.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. You either use parenthesis or `acc_user IN ('username1', 'username1@email.com')`

Comment: use parenthesis. AND has precedence over OR, so the second OR is executed with the ANDs, and then with the first OR.

Comment: Bear in mind that you should not be storing passwords in plaintext. Authentication and security are quite hard to do well - you'd be much better off using a library suitable for your development language.

Comment: for sure. just posted this way for simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

Put some parentheses around those conditions with `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM tblaccount 
WHERE (acc_user = 'username1' OR acc_email = 'username1@email.com' )
   AND acc_password  = 'letmein1' 
   AND acc_confirmed = '1' 
   AND acc_active    = '1';
```

Comment: @Vini - you'll need to add more detail than that to garner a useful response. What else did you try? What data do you have in your database? Try to add all useful and necessary information to your question. Better yet, show us what you have with a SQL Fiddle - otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: nah you were right. acc_confirmed & acc_active fields were set to 0 at the time. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Mahmoud's solution is correct.  You will have to read the operator precedence in mysql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

As `OR` has low precedence than the `AND`, you will have to put the `OR` within the parenthesis as Mahmoud has provided.